# System.out.print(JPanel);

Tags: java, printing

```
core.EditArea[,119,96,556x931,invalid,layout=javax.swing.BoxLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

I have printed out a JPanel, and above is an output. Can anyone tell me what that "invalid" part means?

Better yet, if anyone knows where to find a list of explaned System.out.print(thingy) outputs for as much thingys as possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.out.print(thingy)` is just printing method `thingy.toString()`

`toString()` for `JPanel` comes from `java.awt.Component` class:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "[" + paramString() + "]";
}
```

There is invokation of `protected String paramString()` that leads us back to `JPanel` where this method is overridden:

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of this JPanel. This method 
 * is intended to be used only for debugging purposes, and the 
 * content and format of the returned string may vary between      
 * implementations. The returned string may be empty but may not 
 * be <code>null</code>.
 * 
 * @return  a string representation of this JPanel.
 */
protected String paramString() {
    return super.paramString();
}
```

and this leads us to `JCompomnent` that is first level parent class of `JPanel` (but it still does not have explicitly declared `toString()` so this one from `java.awt.Component` is called for every JComponent, including JPanel).
So, `paramString()` that gets invoked:

```
protected String paramString() {
    String preferredSizeString = (isPreferredSizeSet() ?
                  getPreferredSize().toString() : "");
    String minimumSizeString = (isMinimumSizeSet() ?
                getMinimumSize().toString() : "");
    String maximumSizeString = (isMaximumSizeSet() ?
                getMaximumSize().toString() : "");
    String borderString = (border != null ?
               border.toString() : "");

    return super.paramString() +
    ",alignmentX=" + alignmentX +
    ",alignmentY=" + alignmentY +
    ",border=" + borderString +
",flags=" + flags +             // should beef this up a bit
    ",maximumSize=" + maximumSizeString +
    ",minimumSize=" + minimumSizeString +
    ",preferredSize=" + preferredSizeString;
}
```

... and again - `super.paramString()` - from `java.awt.Container`

```
protected String paramString() {
String str = super.paramString();
LayoutManager layoutMgr = this.layoutMgr;
if (layoutMgr != null) {
    str += ",layout=" + layoutMgr.getClass().getName();
}
return str;
}
```

... and **again** - `super.paramString()` - that **finally** leads us back to `java.awt.Component`

```
protected String paramString() {
    String thisName = getName();
    String str = (thisName != null? thisName : "") + "," + x + "," + y + "," + width + "x" + height;
    if (!isValid()) {
        str += ",invalid";
    }
    if (!visible) {
        str += ",hidden";
    }
    if (!enabled) {
        str += ",disabled";
    }
    return str;
}
```

And here is the root cause of `invalid` that was printed inside your string describing JPanel

```
/**
 * Determines whether this component is valid. A component is valid
 * when it is correctly sized and positioned within its parent
 * container and all its children are also valid. 
 * In order to account for peers' size requirements, components are invalidated
 * before they are first shown on the screen. By the time the parent container 
 * is fully realized, all its components will be valid.
 * @return <code>true</code> if the component is valid, <code>false</code>
 * otherwise
 * @see #validate
 * @see #invalidate
 * @since JDK1.0
 */
public boolean isValid() {
    return (peer != null) && valid;
}
```

How to achieve `valid` state was nicely explained by @Reimeus

Comment: Yeah, I get that, and it outputs thingys properties such as, width, height, layoutmanager, etc...

I want to know what does System.out.print(JPanel) exactly print
As in package.JPanel[,x,y,width,height,etc...

EDIT: you did it.

Comment: What does exactly mean that JPanel is invalid?
How do I fix it?

Comment: @Karlovsky120 I have added source code of `isValid()` to my answer, as well as its javadoc

Comment: @Karlovsky120 My answer was written late at night, so I corrected it now ;)

Answer (score 7):

It's the result of [`isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isValid%28%29) of [`java.awt.Component`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/swing/JComponent.java.html), which is extended by `JPanel`:

> public boolean isValid()
>
> Determines whether this component is valid. A component is valid when
>   it is correctly sized and positioned within its parent container and
>   all its children are also valid. In order to account for peers' size
>   requirements, components are invalidated before they are first shown
>   on the screen. By the time the parent container is fully realized, all
>   its components will be valid.

Comment: Now I know what happend. I instanced a bunch of JPanels in ArrayList, only to paint them later. I called print command just after populating the list...

Answer (score 5):

The 'invalid' field simply means that the components need to be laid out. To make 'valid' can be acheived by 'packing' the parent container, e.g.:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(p);
frame.pack();
```